# Get notification when new file is added to google drive folder along with file details like location/file url

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api, google-drive-shared-drive

I had the developer push notifications for my webhook to get notifications when a new file is added to google drive as per the document.
Document URL: HTTPs://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/push#making-watch-requests

I'm successfully receiving the notifications from google API. But **file details are missing** in the API request which we get. The document clearly states that we will get API requests without a body. So this is not a workout for us.

We were looking at webhook notifications when a new file is added to google drive including file details like the location of the file(File URL). We want that file URL should be stored in our database.

**If any alternative ways to get this done would be great helpful**

Thanks
Vijay